# How To Search Domain Objects And The Physical Files They Point To Using Solr Or Searchable

Tags: java, grails, full-text-search, solr, searchable

I have a digital library system where I store metadata and the path to physical file in the database. The files may be anything: plain text,Word,PDF,MP3,JPEG,MP4...

How can I provide full text search to both my domain objects and the physical files (or some text extraction of the files).

Is my only choice to store the document text in the domain object? I do need to be able to retrieve a list of domain objects regardless of if the search results come from the domain object or the physical document. There is of course a possible connection using the file path and I actually drop each document in a folder named by a GUID, so the connection is there.

I need to do this in Grails, ideally using the solr or searchable plugin, but a Java solution would help.

Comment: what kind of files? i.e. text/pdf/ms word?

Comment: The system supports any file type.

Comment: You'll want to look into Hibernate Search, which integrates Lucene full-text indexing and searching into the Hibernate ORM. - You can have both GORM and Hibernate domain classes within a Grails application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the content in the domain object, just associated the content with the domain object when creating the index entry. I used [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to extract my content, but there are higher level services like [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)

you could code it up in java using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) directly but I would suggest [SOLR](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage) instead

[grails searchable plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/searchable) based on [Compass](http://www.compass-project.org/) which is based on [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me an example or point me to the right documentation?

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of searchable; its really being replaced by the solr plugin it seams. What I'm looking for is an example of *how* to get the physical docs indexed. E.g., how do I tell solr (or searchable) to 1) index my domain object and 2) follow the path to the physical document pointed to by Domain.uri and index the physical document along with the domain object. (1) is clearly documented, but I'm looking for help with (2). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this article](http://metagear.de/articles/hibernate-search-sample/index.html) that covers use cases like yours, based on [Spring](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html), [Hibernate](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html#15.2%20Mapping%20with%20Hibernate%20Annotations), Hibernate Search, and JSF. It comes with a comprehensive, well-documented, [sample application](http://metagear.de/articles/hibernate-search-sample/library-sample.war).

Which is focusing on the *separations of concerns* paradigm and *modularity*, BTW. Thus, the concepts involved that concern full-text searching ought to suit fine with Grails, or other, Java-based, applications.

The main **domain class** is `de.metagear.library.model.Media` (there is an associated `MetaData` domain class, too). You'll be able to mix Hibernate and GORM classes; however, you'll need to use different APIs then.

The `Media` class contains a property `plainText`:

```
@Column(name = "plain_text", nullable = false)
@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@Lob
private String plainText;
```

That property holds the *extracted* text (i.e., from PDFs, etc.). I'm not sure whether it needs to be saved to the database or not (probably not, but it should't harm too much otherwise). Nevertheless, it's *not* used for full-text search (see below). For full-text search, the Lucene indexes are used, only.

Before a `Media` is created, the text contents of the corresponding orginal document (possibly, a binary one) is extracted. The `de.metagear.library.model.factory.MediaFactory.getInstance(..)` method **extracts the text**, stores the extracted text in a new `Media` object, and returns that `Media`.

In the sample, it simply stores the original document into a property of the domain object, but, at that place, you could also save the document to file and store a reference (the GUID you'd mentioned) into a `Media`'s property.

The domain class is **saved** by the `de.metagear.library.dao.MediaCrudDaoImpl` class, which is a Spring bean. Internally, it's using an injected `EntityManagerFactory` that, in */applicationContext.xml*, has been defined to use Hibernate under the hood.

**Indexing** occurs, automatically, because of the Hibernate annotations in the domain class.

As for performing the **full-text search** itself, that's accomplished by the `de.metagear.library.dao.MediaSearchDaoImpl.getSearchResults(..)` method that does *not* query the database, but the Lucene indexes, only.

The sample application contains a powerful query terms pre-processor that can combine AND, OR, and NOT operators on different indexes while preserving the comprehensive [Lucene expression syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html).

By setting a custom `org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer` at this place, objects of any type (including domain classes, of course) can be returned.

---

I haven't looked into the Grails Searchable plugin, yet, and, thus, cannot tell whether it's viable in terms of robustness, maintainability, ease of use, and - last-not-least - extensibility with custom or third-party content extractors, parsers, and analyzers. Probably, it is, as well.

After all, there's a basic knowledge of the Spring and (maybe) the Hibernate framework involved with my approach. These are just the frameworks that Grails and Gorm are based on, but I think that this might make a decision point for you.

At least, looking at the above concepts ought to be informative and empower to advance when looking at different frameworks and approaches.

Thanks.

Comment: The app looks good. Thanks. It looks like you're storing the extracted text into the database and it's the database content that gets indexed. Right? It seems like that's what I'm going to have to do. But I was hoping to avoid that by having the text kept in the file system.

Comment: `@Field(store = Store.YES)` should mean that the class' field's contents is completely stored in the Lucene index. This should also work without the `@Column`, thus, without saving it to the database, redundantly, - given that `query.setProjection(..)` is used as done in `MediaSearchDaoImpl.getSearchResults(..)`. - Please refer to the Hibernate Search Reference for that issue, thanks.